# Tweet collection using Python Tweepy

Tags: python, json, csv, twitter

I am collecting  Data from twitter for data analysis using python tweepy.
     code is:
[image: Python tweepy code]

Data is saved in json format.But i need to convert it in .csv format.
Data sample is:
[image: Data sample]

But it is showing error that json is invalid.
Can you tell me how can i convert this data in .csv format.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)

Answer (score 0):

JSON data must be a single object, whereas you have an object every line. It's better to store it as an array of objects as that is considered valid JSON.

eg

```
[{"created_at"...},
{"created_at"...},
{"created_at"...}]
```

Comment: Well the only difference in the format is the square brackets and the commas. You should fine a way to add '[' to the start of the file when you're creating it, append a ',' to the end of every line after writing the Tweet object and then add a ']' when you're finished instead of the final comma.